# Footing for deck on slope with one side near grade

Tags: deck, footings, slope

I am extending my deck and plan to make it a freestanding deck (just to avoid attaching to the current one but it will be close on top).

I plan to have a row of 4 posts on the lower level (left). Each post has 4x4 on top of pier block with metal bracket (same as existing deck):

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Concrete-Pier-Block-with-Metal-Bracket-8053112/202820094

Then on the upper slope, I am planning to use 2x8 and put on top of this pier posts:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/10-in-x-10-in-x-8-in-Concrete-Deck-Block-012023A/205613606

[image]

Do you think this is OK?

Comment: Depends how you plan to use those blocks. Are you planning to bury them 30" deep? http://www.decks.com/how-to/573/can-i-use-deck-pier-blocks-instead-of-footing

Comment: I won't be burying them completely but leave like 1/3 above the ground.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked?  That type block should be sunk to be below the frostline.   @benWelborn answer is awesome.

Comment: Yes I read all the articles in that link. We are in Seattle so no frost line. But I am planning to dig 1 foot deep, fill with 5/8" minus like 3-4 inches, then put the blocks on top.

Comment: Depending which map you look at the frostline in Seattle is either 18" or 24"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those pier blocks or deck blocks are a waste of money. It's not going to be as difficult to dig a few holes and install some real posts now as it will be after the deck is complete and has sunken (unevenly). They might be okay for a light duty shed or dog house, but nothing significant, like a deck.

Edit based on comment:

[image]

Comment: Sure. But from architecture stand point, do you think it's OK to have 1 side using 4x4 post while the other side using the 4x8 as the beam directly on the pier footing?

Comment: @HP 4x8 or 2x8? (or two 2x8s together?); the concrete blocks are made for 2x8... or various sizes. Supposing that you had solid footing, it would be ok. Editing answer with pictures.

Comment: The block is for 4x8 like http://www.lowes.com/pd_476202-10926-476202___?Ntt=4x8+deck+beam&UserSearch=4x8+deck+beam&productId=4777788 because it's the beam right? I mean I can't just use 2x8 for beam, no? I guess my main concern is if it's OK architecturally to have 4x4 posts on one side and just beam directly on blocks on the other side.

Comment: @HP Whether you set the beam on a block or a post doesn't make the difference. Without getting distracted by technical exceptions, you could use a 2x8 if you have it thouroghly supported. If you use a 4x8 beam, then it should be able to hold more weight, and/or require less support. But since the support will be blocks placed on the ground, I would probably use 4x8 plus extra blocks for support (distribute the weight). Sinking blocks/support is the primary concern.