# Am I required to use footings when building a deck or can I just have the posts resting on the ground? (Wisconsin)

Tags: deck, building-regulations, footings

I want to build a deck for my house but I don't really want to dig holes and pour concrete for the footings. Can I just build the deck on ground level using something like this to support the posts?

[image: Block]

The location is in Wisconsin. The deck wouldn't be more than 2-3 feet off the ground at any point. Also, The deck would be free-standing and not directly attached to the house.

Comment: I use pier blocks all the time they save time and provides support. With a narrow deck that is not connected to the structure expect to put in cross bracing even at 2' tall or it may be quite wobbly.

Comment: I'd be worry about the freeze/thaw cycle causing shifting over time.

Comment: This is question fairly similar to: [Footing for deck on slope with one side near grade](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/90487/footing-for-deck-on-slope-with-one-side-near-grade)... in essence, those pier blocks or deck blocks are a waste of money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to get confirmation on an answer from a local building inspector. As per Wisconsin Administrative Code SPS 321.15(2)(f)

> **(f)** *Deck footings*. Decks attached to dwellings and detached decks which serve an exit shall be supported on a structural system designed to transmit and safely distribute the loads to the soil. Footings shall be sized to not exceed the allowable material stresses. The bearing area shall be at least equal to the area required to transfer the loads to the supporting soil without exceeding the bearing values of the soil.

[SPS 321.15(2)(f)](https://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/document/administrativecode/SPS%20321.15(2)(f))

So in essence, if there is a door that leads onto the deck it must have proper footings in the ground (as explained to me).